# Remove a list from a list

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of co-ordinates and a function which works out the distance between them.

I'm trying to make a function that takes a start point and a list of co-ordinates as input. The function then finds the closest point to the start point, then finds the closest point to that etc...

The problem I'm having is the co-ordinate previous to the next may be the closest so at that point it's repeating, so I need to remove this.

```
def getroute(start, allpoints):
    routelist = [start]
    next = getclosestpoint(start, allpoints)
    allpoints.remove(start)
    for i in range(0,len(allpoints)):
        routelist.append(next)
        *allpoints.remove(next[1])*
        next = getclosestpoint(next[1], allpoints)
    return routelist
```

I keep getting the error:

```
allpoints.remove(next[1])
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

but when I print next[1] I get eg [4, 1] which is in my list of allpoints: [-3, -3], [1,-1], [4,1], [-2,5]

Can anyone explain why it isn't removing that?

Thanks.

Update:
I think I've managed it with the below:

```
latlngs = [[-3, -3], [1,-1], [4,1], [-2,5], [2,2], [-6,1]]

def gethypot(latlng):
    hypot = sqrt(pow(latlng[0],2)+pow(latlng[1],2))
    return hypot

def getdistance(point1, point2):
    lat_apart = point2[0] - point1[0]
    lng_apart = point2[1] - point1[1]
    distance = gethypot([lat_apart,lng_apart])
    return distance

def getclosestpoint(start, points):
    allpoints = points
    distances = []
    allpoints.remove(start)
    shortest = 0
    for i in range(0,len(allpoints)):
        distances.append(getdistance(start,allpoints[i]))       
        if getdistance(start,allpoints[i]) == min(distances):
            shortest = allpoints[i]
    return shortest

def getroute(start, allpoints):
    routelist = [start]
    points = allpoints
    next = getclosestpoint(start, points)
    for i in range(0,len(points)):
        routelist.append(next)
        next = getclosestpoint(next, points)
    return routelist
```

Comment: You shouldn't change a list you're currently iterating over

Comment: What value does allpoints hold?

Comment: I'm not able to figure out what you're trying to achieve, but just some two cents: The first element of a list is accessed with `foo_list[0]`, where `foo_list` is any list.

Comment: Aside: this isn't relevant to this question, but `next` is the name of a very useful built-in function and so not a good name to use for a variable, as tempting as it is.  I usually wind up adding the appropriate noun, like `next_point` or `next_closest_point` or something.

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop is wrong. Effectively, you want to move all points from `allpoints` to `routelist`, so you could use:

```
def getroute(start, allpoints):
    routelist = []
    next = start
    while allpoints:
        routelist.append(next)
        allpoints.remove(next)
        _, next = getclosestpoint(next, allpoints)
    return routelist
```

Comment: I've tried that and it's now telling me: list.remove(x): x not in list.  Which is frustrating, because it is in the list...

Comment: At which step; the first iteration, when `next = start`, or later?

Comment: Sorry, you must have edited your answer, I was referring to the routelist -1 bit. I've just tried this and coming up with the same error at this point: allpoints.remove(next)

Comment: I think it's because when there is only one item left in the list it's breaking.

Comment: @PaulBentham when there is only one item left, `getclosestpoint` should still return that item, I don't see why that would break it. You may need to look into how that function is implemented, or add some `print`s into `getroute` to explore how `next`, `routelist` and `allpoints` change through each iteration.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to keep digging. Still some problems with the solution I posted above too. thanks for the help.

Comment: What does `getclosestpoint` return? If it's a list, the first item is `next[0]`.

Comment: It returns the distance and then the co-ordinates, so it would return [5.4, [3,-1]]

Comment: I've amended my question to show the working code now, can you see any potential flaws in that?

Comment: @PaulBentham `points = allpoints` doesn't do anything - that's just a reference, not a copy. Try `points = allpoints[:]`. However, having `getclosestpoint` mutate the list of points seems counterintuitive, and may trip you up later.